# How to use Dialogflow queries with special characters like '#'?

Tags: dialogflow-es

if I use a query string like:

> Does John know to code in C#?

Dialogflow cannot match the C# as an entity parameter. But if I ask like:

> Does John know to code in C#

Without any following characters, Dialogflow can match C# as entity parameter. What can be the reason for this? I have tried template and also example queries for training the intent but the result is the same for both.

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Thanks for your question. It looks like this may be a bug - we're currently investigating.

Comment: thank you @DanImrie-Situnayake